# How to separate all value in array from single string

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have array like

```
let array = ["a,b,c"]
```

I want to convert It like this

```
let array = ["a","b","c"]
```

Comment: Please add more detail, this is a example anwser: `["a,b,c"].map(v => v.split(',')).flat()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = ["a,b,c"]
console.log(array.join().split(","))
```

Comment: Please join with `separator`, the answer must work with any `separator`, someone can confuse with default parameter of `Array.prototype.join`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). It allows you to return arrays which fill be flattened.

```js
let array = ["a,b,c"];
console.log(array.flatMap(item => item.split(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const array = ["a,b,c"];

const output = array[0].split(",");

console.log(output);
```